# How to add static content to a GWT project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

any quick hint to an article for adding static content to 
a GWT project (ex:images)

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You have basically two ways of doing this:

1. ImageResource [Article 1](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#ImageResource) [Article 2](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiImageBundles.html)
2. You can just drag and drop your image into the war-folder of your project. If you want to display that image you would just create an HTML object and use the setContent()-function to display it(using the img-tag you know from HTML)

I would use number 1 because it uses css sprites to optimize the loading time of your application.