# How to Add Static Resources in a GWT Application?

Tags: gwt, web-applications, project-structure, google-eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

I am trying to add a PNG graphic to a GWT 2.6 application in Eclipse Kepler, using the latest plugins.

I have found numerous StackOverflow questions dealing with this topic, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502166/where-do-i-put-static-files-for-gwt-app-war-folder-or-public-folder), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761019/how-to-add-static-content-to-a-gwt-project-in-eclipse?rq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496794/how-to-give-the-default-path-in-gwt), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071517/path-for-images-folder-in-gwt-project) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222732/gwt-static-resource-from-subfolders-not-found). Likewise, there are plenty of resources on the web, such as [this](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1959965), [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/ic4f38EKQy0) or [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwt-maven/LlUS5pIo-ws). Ultimately, there are the [official docs on the project structure](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions).

They all boil down to putting static resources such as image files into the `war` or the `public` folder.

Now, my default project structure created by Eclipse does not seem to contain any folder named `public`, so I am not sure where that one would be supposed to be located, but I have tried on two machines placing the files in the `war` folder. Evidently, **this does not work**, as the custom contents of the `war` folder is deleted every time I recompile the project.

**What am I doing wrong; where are image files or other custom static resources supposed to be placed in my project?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the `war` folder shouldn't be deleted, except for the specific folder that GWT writes into (`war/myapp`, assuming you have a `rename-to="myapp"` in your `.gwt.xml`). If it does, then there's either a bug in the Google Plugin for Eclipse or a misconfiguration of your Eclipse project.

Re. the `public` folder, it should sit just next to your `.gwt.xml` file (and `client`, `server` and/or `shared` subpackages)

Whether you'll use one or the other depends on how your module will be used:

- If it's a library and you want to ship the resource with it, then use `public`; and make sure you use sufficiently unique file/folder names so as to not cause conflicts.
- If it's a library and you want to force people to provide their own resource, then *don't* use `public` (you could also make a distinct module just for the resources, that people will be free to use or not).
- If it's an application, then pick whatever you want. I tend to prefer `war`.

Comment: Hm, true, `war/images` does not get deleted. Seems like I had always tried `war/<projectname>/images`, because an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071517/path-for-images-folder-in-gwt-project) said so.